# Heads up notification don't appear when notification arrives

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I am trying to display notifications for an android app. The notification appears perfectly in the notification area but the [heads up notification](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications) doesn't appear even after setting the priority to "max".
Here is my code for notification builder

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Log.e("notification arrived","");

    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification.Builder n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Best Deals")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(pattern);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, n.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and everything works as expected for me.

[image]

Maybe you have to change your test environment?

I've used a Nexus 7 emulator with API 25.
These are inside my `build.gradle`:

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 23
```

> **Note:** Some devices/manufacturers gives you the option to disable (or have disabled it by default) the heads up Notifications.